# How to enable administrator using guest

Tags: 12.04

I mistakenly disabled my administrator account in Ubuntu 12. Now all my documents are locked. I have tried entering the password but it's responding with "invalid password". I'm only able to login using the guest account.

How can I re-enable my administrator account?

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted, or is there just permisssions errors?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/402020/how-to-enable-administrator-account/402022#402022